# How to set setVariant in roomconfig

Tags: google-play, google-play-games

I read that setvariant can be as many the game need, in a range of 1-1023 is that true or only one variant, I am coding something like this since the code will be use by other and they can put an array of int (range value was previous verify)

```
        for(int var : variant) {
            roomConfigBuilder.setVariant(var);
        }
```

I don't know if that make sense or not.

also clarify me something does it work with automatch, when mix automatch and invited players.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that setvariant can be as many the game need, in a range of 1-1023 is that true or only one variant

setVariant value is developer-controlled, and will describe what type of game to play. If not set, it will use the [Room constants](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/Room) to set it.

> also clarify me something does it work with automatch, when mix automatch and invited players.

From the [Real-time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer) developer page,

> Optionally, you might want to ensure that only players who are interested in a specific type of game variant are auto-matched to the room.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, read the help is not a problem the issue here is that if certainly is tested and it is working this way, since I am testing with not luck.